# jQuery execute function once, 1 second after window resize ended

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to execute a function 1 second after window resize ended?

For example for this code:

```
$(window).bind("resize", methodToFixLayout);
function methodToFixLayout(e) {

... some code ...

};
```

Basically I want to execute some css changes but only ONCE, 1 second after last window resize.. Right now this triggers too many times and makes everything very slow..

Comment: use `setTimeout()` or `.delay()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var timer;
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
  if(timer)
    clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function(){ /* Whatever you want here */ }, 1000);
});
```

The resize event will fire rapidly if the user is constantly dragging the window, this method will trigger an action when dragging has ceased for 1 second.

EDIT:
Good comments by roasted and adeneo, it's fewer steps / more efficient to simply invoke clearTimeout(timer) without checking to see if a timer has even been set

```
var timer;
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function(){ /* Whatever you want here */ }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: It is maybe more readable but `if(timer)` is useless here, just FYI i said that. Anyway +1

Comment: @roasted - I tend to agree, it probably takes longer to check if there is a timer, then to just clear it even if it's not set.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need a timeOut, and since the resize event fires continuosly you should clear the timeout on a new resize to make sure it doesn't fire multiple times :

```
var timer;

$(window).on("resize", function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        ... some code ...
    },1000);
});
```

or without the global:

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
    $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
            ... some code ...
        },1000)
    );
});
```

Comment: I hardly believe you want timer in global scope, right?! Ok, i need to sleep :=)

Comment: @roasted - If it where me, I'd use data() for the timer, but a global shows the point much better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var timer;

$(window).bind("resize", methodToFixLayout);
  function methodToFixLayout(e) {
    if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
      ... some code ...
    },1000);
};
```

Comment: Without clearing the timeout, the desired effect of a single function invocation after the user is finished resizing the window wont occur. Instead an invocation will occur each time the window dimensions are changed by a pixel.

Answer (score 0):

You need [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

E.G.

```
var timeout;

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }

  timeout = setTimeout(yourMethodToFixLayout, 1000);
});
```

Demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LcAIC